# OSX: How do I convert a static library to a dynamic one?

Tags: macos, dynamic, linker, static-libraries

Suppose I have a third party library called somelib.a on a Mac running Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.4 installed. I want to get a dynamic library out of it called somelib.dylib. An appropriate Linux command would be:

```
g++ -fpic -shared -Wl,-whole-archive somelib.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive -o somelib.so
```

where -whole-archive and -no-whole-archive are passed to the linker.
When I do the equivalent for Mac:

```
g++ -fpic -shared -Wl,-whole-archive somelib.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive -o somelib.dylib
```

ld fails with an error:

```
ld: unknown option: -whole-archive
```

It seems that the ld on OSX is different from GNU ld. How do I have to modify above command so I will get the desired result?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found out the solution to my problem:

```
g++ -fpic -shared -Wl,-force_load somelib.a -o somelib.dylib
```

The required argument is `-force_load`:

- Which needs to be followed by a single library you wanna ensure gets loaded.
- I mean, it needs to be repeated for each library (unlike `-noall_load` approach, which wrapped them).
- For example, `-Wl,-force_load libYetAnotherFile.a` (where `-Wl,` part is only required because we don't pass parameter directly to linker).

**Note** that *Old answer* <sup>(before edit)</sup> was using `-noall_load` instead, but nowadays that causes a linker error (as `-noall_load` has been removed, was obsolete previously).

Comment: What's the most likely diagnosis if this — with or without `-force_load` substituted for `-all_load` apparently condenses a 1.2mb .a into a 4kb .dylib?

Comment: @Tommy I just saw your comment now. I would guess that it extracts only the symbols that you actually use and you use only a very small part of that archive.

Comment: getting error - `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: Nowadays `-force_load` is the only solution!! Because `-noall_load` causes a nice linker error (as it's been removed, was obsolete previously).

Comment: @Top-Master is that a simple one-to-one replacement in the original answer? I would gladly update my answer bu I do not have a mac to test on.

Comment: The only difference is that `-force_load` requires to be repeated for each library (like "`-force_load libA.a -force_load -lB -force_load libC.a`", where `-lB` is same as `libB.a`).

Answer (score 5):

Note: A link for the documentation of the OSX `ld` linker.

http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ld/

I know it is late to give an answer for this, but I do not have enough reputation to make a comment on @hanslovsky answer.
However, it helps me a lot to have the docs of the options too. 
It helps what the options do exactly, and that other options the `ld` linker also has.
So I just wanted to share with others who finds linking an issue.

### UPDATE:

After the comment from @GhostCat I have decided to expand my answer.

The docs for `-all_load` is:

> *-all_load*
>
> > ```
> > Loads all members of static archive libraries.
> > ```

So it loads for all static libraries that you note. 
If you want something similar to `--whole-archive` and `--no-whole-archive`, then you need to use `-force_load` and `-noall_load`.

*-force_load* "path_to_archive"

> Loads all members of the specified static archive library.  Note: -
>      all_load forces all members of all archives to be loaded.
>      This option allows you to target a specific archive.

*-noall_load*

> This is the default.  This option is obsolete.

Then you can define which libraries to fully load with `-force_load` and then later turn it off again with `-noall_load`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have given my answer more depth now.

Comment: If you modify the solution in my answer to use the flags in your answer and add it to your answer, I will accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

According to the `ld` manual, `-noall_load` is the default and is ignored. (If you use it, you get an error message: `ld: warning: option -noall_load is obsolete and being ignored`)

Apparently the way to get `-all_load` to apply to only one library is as follows:

```
-Wl,-force_load,somelib.a
```

Comment: I do not have  a Mac right now, but I will try this later, thank you.