# Compiling in a dynamic C library (dylib) into a program on OS X

Tags: c, macos, static-linking

I've written a little C program which uses `libusb`. Now I want to distribute this program to "normal" (not dev) Mac OS X computers. But when I ported the compiled file to a test machine I got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kitty/myprogram
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

When I copy the files (works only with all the files)

```
/opt/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib   /opt/local/lib/libusb-1.0.a     
/opt/local/lib/libusb.a
/opt/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib   /opt/local/lib/libusb-1.0.dylib     
/opt/local/lib/libusb.dylib
```

from my machine to the target machine the program works flawlessly.

**But I really want to create or compile everything into a single executable.** How is this possible?

Using `-static` while compiling does not work since not all libraries can be compiled into the final app statically (see [this SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801032/2429611)).

So how can I make a single neat little application file?

Answer (score 2):

You can [convert a static library to a dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082470/osx-how-do-i-convert-a-static-library-to-a-dynamic-one), but I'm not aware of a way to do the reverse as you want it.

If you're building an app with a bundle, you need to put the library you want to distribute inside your bundle, in the `Frameworks` directory, and link against that.

If you are *not* building a bundle-based app, just a single binary, you may need to provide instructions for your users on how to install the library on their system (e.g. via Homebrew).

**Here's how you do it for bundle-based apps:**

Apple has a [document about run-path dependent libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html) but doesn't actually explain how to set this up for a newbie.

Here's how it should work:

- Add the `libusb.dylib` you want to use to your project.
- It should automatically get added to your *"Link Binary with Libraries"* phase in your project's *"Build Phases"*. If not, add it here.
- Add a new *"Copy Files"* build phase.

  - In the *"Destination"* drop-down box, select *"Frameworks"*. This is the 
    Frameworks directory in your app's final bundle.
  - Then press the *"+"* icon in that copy build phase and add your library.
- If you had any manual linking options like `-L/usr/local/lib` and `-lusb`, remove them.
- Clean and build.

When you now look into your app bundle, you'll see that the library is copied to `<bundle_path>/Contents/Frameworks/`. You can now start the app from wherever you want, the dynamic link loader knows it needs to look at `<path_to_binary>/../Frameworks/` to find your library.

**But:** you may need to rebuild your `libusb` to have the `install_name` set to `@rpath/../Frameworks/libusb.dylib` or use the `install_name_tool` CLI tool fix that path for your copy of `libusb.dylib` that you added to your project.